# Use XSLT/XPATH to select elements having a child element with a specific value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a large (200k lines) XML file as a report from a tool (reporting on a VSS database). It consists of a large number of `<file>` elements like this:

```
<file>
 <name>file.bat</name>
 <version>111</version>
 <checkedout>No</checkedout>
 <binary>Text</binary>
 <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
 <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
 <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
 <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
 <comment></comment>
 <label>1.2.3.4</label>
 <label_comment></label_comment>
 <user>John</user>
 <shared_links>
  <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
  <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
 </shared_links>
</file>
```

I want to find *only* the `<file>` elements which have at least one `<shared_link>` starting with/prefixed by "$/Beta".

In an ideal world, all I want for each matching element are the `<name>`, `<vss_path>` and (matching) `<shared_link>` parts, but that's not exactly important.

I'm not well-versed in XSLT/XPATH but believe those can do something like this?

Comment: Sorry for the poor title, and I'm not 100% certain XPath is relevant... edits welcome.

Comment: I have not tried this so I am posting this as a comment. You are looking at something like this `//file[shared_links[starts-with(shared_link, '$/Beta_1')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="file[shared_links[shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]]]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name | vss_path | shared_links"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="shared_links">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input XML (as yours but with an extra, non-matching file added):

```
<root>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <version>111</version>
    <checkedout>No</checkedout>
    <binary>Text</binary>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
    <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
    <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
    <comment></comment>
    <label>1.2.3.4</label>
    <label_comment></label_comment>
    <user>John</user>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Alpha_1</shared_link>
      <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <version>111</version>
    <checkedout>No</checkedout>
    <binary>Text</binary>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
    <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
    <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
    <comment></comment>
    <label>1.2.3.4</label>
    <label_comment></label_comment>
    <user>John</user>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
      <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
</root>
```

produces the following output XML:

```
<root>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//file[shared_links/shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file">
  <xsl:copy-of select="name | vss_path | shared_links/shared_link"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to output those elements. That way however the result is an XML fragment with multiple top level elements, if you want an XML document then change the first template to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//file[shared_links/shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]]"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I used Ben's version and it worked well but yours looks much neater. I'd rather select the best answer but I don't know enough to understand which that is!

Comment: Also can you wrap yours up as a complete XSL file? i.e. something I can copy-paste into http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php and test?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of putting Martin Honnen's solution into a complete XSLT stylesheet. You can see the results [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/qY1ppd). Click "View Source" on the "Output" window. The results are slightly different from mine in that: (1) the `<shared_link>` elements are not inside a `<shared_links>` element and (2) all `<shared_link>` elements are output (not just the ones that start with "$/Beta". Of course, this may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Martin, there are missing closing "]" in your XPath that selects `<file>` elements.