# Select XML nodes based on two different attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is based on the same input data as in this question: [Use XSLT/XPATH to select elements having a child element with a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055749/use-xslt-xpath-to-select-elements-having-a-child-element-with-a-specific-value)

However I need to now select only `<file>` elements where:

1. at least one `<shared_element>` starts "$/Beta"
2. **`<user>` is "John"**

.2. is the only addition to the previous question... I tried adding in an additional test but my XSLT is too bad to understand how to do this. Ideally I want to know how to modify the XSL in the accepted answer but a general "how to require values on separate elements/attributes" example is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify the XPath predicate in the select statement inside the template that matches `root`. Here's a modified version of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="file[shared_links[shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]] and user='John']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name | vss_path | shared_links | user"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="shared_links">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="shared_link[starts-with(., '$/Beta')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input XML (extra test case added):

```
<root>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <version>111</version>
    <checkedout>No</checkedout>
    <binary>Text</binary>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
    <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
    <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
    <comment></comment>
    <label>1.2.3.4</label>
    <label_comment></label_comment>
    <user>John</user>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Alpha_1</shared_link>
      <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <version>111</version>
    <checkedout>No</checkedout>
    <binary>Text</binary>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
    <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
    <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
    <comment></comment>
    <label>1.2.3.4</label>
    <label_comment></label_comment>
    <user>John</user>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
      <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>file.bat</name>
    <version>111</version>
    <checkedout>No</checkedout>
    <binary>Text</binary>
    <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
    <original_path>C:\code\file.bat</original_path>
    <action>Labeled &apos;1.2.3.4&apos;</action>
    <date>27/09/2013 09:08:00</date>
    <comment></comment>
    <label>1.2.3.4</label>
    <label_comment></label_comment>
    <user>Ben</user>
    <shared_links>
      <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
      <shared_link>$/Branches/New_Feature</shared_link>
    </shared_links>
  </file>
</root>
```

it produces the following output:

```
<root>
   <file>
      <name>file.bat</name>
      <vss_path>$/Code/file.bat</vss_path>
      <user>John</user>
      <shared_links>
         <shared_link>$/Beta_1</shared_link>
      </shared_links>
   </file>
</root>
```